# Doctrine MongoDB Referencing and Inheritance

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm

I am having problems with Doctrine MongoDB ODM. Scenario is very simple (I think).
I have set of documents with COLLECTION_PER_CLASS inheritance model (Base, Product, etc). This all works well and I can persist objects as usual.

```
/**
 * @ODM\Document(collection="content_base")
 * @ODM\InheritanceType("COLLECTION_PER_CLASS")
 */
class Base {

/**
 * @ODM\Document(collection="content_products")
 */
class Product extends Base {
```

Now, I have another Document (Item) and I want to create ReferenceOne to inherited Documents:

```
/**
 * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Base")
 */
private $content;
```

And this is where I am having problems, because Doctrine ClassLoader complains about class Base being redeclared:

```
 Fatal error: include(): Cannot redeclare class content\documents\types\base in /vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 183
```

I am a bit confused why would this be a problem, or otherwise what is correct way of doing this?

**UPDATE**

I have just noticed, if I remove 'targetDocument' from ReferenceOne annotation I get results I wanted. Is this the correct way to do it?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Maybe a dummy question but: have you declared the Base class in the same php file of the Product class?

Comment: Nope, I never do that. Funny thing is, that it works as expected anyway so I suppose it's not really an issue at the moment. I was just interested on the "official" resolution/clarification to the problem I was experiencing.